# Unable to display images for Jumbotron and Mobile Stepper UI component (Material UI)

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to import some images in my create-react-app project into a jumbo-tron and Mobile Stepper UI component using the Material UI library. All the images are being imported into and exported out of an Image.js file component to be passed down as objects in the designated components of choice. Although, when inspecting the elements I'm able to detect the imported objects in my developer tools the actually images aren't displaying visually as expected. In this use case, All the images are being imported into the Image.js file are coming from an images folder in the src/ directory.

I tried using the absolute relative path by placing the static assets (images) in the public folder, but ran into the same problem. After reading the docs I decided that the importing of images would be best for my use case after moving to production in my scenario.

```
import  Background  from '../Components/Images';


  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className={classes.mainFeaturedPost}>
       <Grid container >
        <Grid item md={6}>
          <div className={classes.mainFeaturedPostContent}>
            <img src={Background} alt="backGround" />
```

[Jumbo-tron screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJqv.jpg)

Mobile Stepper Component UI code

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MobileStepper from '@material-ui/core/MobileStepper';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';
import Home from './Images';
import Login from './Images';
import LoggedIn from './Images';
import Register from './Images';

const tutorialSteps = [
  {
    label: 'Home Screen',
    imgPath:
      {Home}, 
  },
  {
    label: 'Login Page',
    imgPath:
    {Login},
  },
  {
    label: 'Logged-in User',
    imgPath:
     {LoggedIn},
  },
  {
    label: 'User Registration',
    imgPath:
   {Register},
  },

  {
    label: 'Goč, Serbia',
    imgPath:
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512341689857-198e7e2f3ca8?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60',
  },
];

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 400,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  header: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 50,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
  },
  img: {
    height: 250,
    maxWidth: 400,
    overflow: 'visible',
    display: 'block',
    width: '100%',
  },
});

class TextMobileStepper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeStep: 0,
  };

  handleNext = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1,
    }));
  };

  handleBack = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      activeStep: prevState.activeStep - 1,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;
    const { activeStep } = this.state;
    const maxSteps = tutorialSteps.length;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}  >
        <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.header}

        >
          <Typography>{tutorialSteps[activeStep].label}</Typography>
        </Paper>
        <img
          className={classes.img}
          src={tutorialSteps[activeStep].imgPath}
          alt={tutorialSteps[activeStep].label}
        />
        <MobileStepper
          steps={maxSteps}
          position="static"
          activeStep={activeStep}
          className={classes.mobileStepper}
          nextButton={
            <Button size="small" onClick={this.handleNext} disabled={activeStep === maxSteps - 1}>
              Next
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
            </Button>
          }
          backButton={
            <Button size="small" onClick={this.handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
              {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
              Back
            </Button>
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TextMobileStepper.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(TextMobileStepper);
```

[Stepper screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I4fz.jpg)

[Jumbo-tron console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuHvp.jpg)
[Mobile Stepper console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO0SS.jpg)

Comment: What is the value of `Background`?

Comment: A background cover picture I'm trying to use as a jumbo-tron image

Comment: does it work in development? shouldn't it be the path to that image?

Comment: It's not working in development there seems to be a broken image icon appearing instead of the intended picture I want to use. The same thing is happening with the Mobile Stepper UI component as well. But I can see the object in my developer tools when inspecting the element.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console either

Comment: Have you tried to import the image from a different folder?

Comment: No I've only tried switching between the public and src directory and changed the capitalization of the folder name.

Comment: As far as I understand the `src` attribute expects a path string not an image file. have you tried to give it the path to the file?

Comment: @cowCrazy Yes I have. The path string is given to the object in the Image.js file then exported as an object using export default to later be imported into other components on the project.